# How to pass data to slots in components?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

A concrete example. I want to build a component for Bootstrap's grid layout. I want to be able to do something like this (this is invalid Vue code):

**BGrid.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <slot name="col" class="'col' + colNumber"></col>
    </div>
  </div>
<template>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <b-grid>
      <template slot="name" :colNumber="2">
        <p>Content for the column 1</p>
      </template>
     <template slot="name" :colNumber="4">
        <p>Content for the column 2</p>
      </template>
    </b-grid>
  </div>
<template>
```

(I want to be able to have different `colNumbers` for different col slots.)

Is there a way to accomplish something similar in Vue?

Comment: Why not just pass it as a prop to the `b-grid` component?

Comment: @BertEvans could you give me a sample code? Would I still be able to add content to the slot? How to control which slot has which colNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to emit a `div` with the class set to the `col-` plus the column number, you can pass the column number as a property to the component.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("b-grid",{
  props:["colNumber"],
  template: `
    <div class="container"><slot></slot></div>
  `
})

Vue.component("row",{
  template: `
    <div class="row"><slot></slot></div>
  `
})

Vue.component("column",{
  props:["colNumber"],
  template:`
     <div :class="'col-' + colNumber">
         <slot></slot>
     </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-grid>
    <row>
      <column :col-number="2">
        <p>Content for 2 column</p>
      </column>
      <column :col-number="6">
        <p>Content for 6 column</p>
      </column>
    </row>
  </b-grid>
</div>
```

In the above example, inspect the content to see that the class is set properly.

Comment: What if I want different `colNumbers` for different columns? Please see my updated question.

Comment: @alex I wouldn't use slots for that, I would use column components probably. If this is to replicate Bootstrap's grid system you likely want a container, rows, and columns right?

Comment: Ah, ha. The reason I wanted to use slots was because I didn't want to create two components. Guess this is the only way?

Comment: @alex it's not the only way, but if you use slots, you will be restricted in your grid definition. Are you going to define 12 slots and not populate some of them sometimes?

Comment: Never mind, guess your approach makes the most sense (plus is clearer). Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146809/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-alex).